# indexof() returns -1 all the time when trying to record to local storage on changed route vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to record page id in the local storage only if it doesn't exist there already. I've created this function but it dosen't work properly because `indexof()` always returns `-1` and it records the same id multiple times.

```
updateProgress (id) {
  let old = localStorage.getItem('visited').split(',')
  if (old === null) old = ' '
  if (old.indexOf(id) === -1) {
    let newProgress = [old, id]
    localStorage.setItem('visited', newProgress.join(','))
  }
}
```

Id is always a string.
If I do `console.log(localStorage.getItem('visited'))`it returns:

```
8,3,1,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,2,4,3,1,2,2,2,2,1,15,1,2,2,2,1
```

**Update:** What I noticed is that if I refresh the page then it doesn't add new value but if I change the route to another id it add it again. To sum up, this is probably vue.js issue because id is taken from the route and it is called like this:

```
  created () {
    this.updateProgress(this.id)
  },
  watch: {
    '$route' () {
      this.updateProgress(this.id)
    }
```

So when the function is called in `created()` it works fine but when it gets called when looking for route changes it doesn't work right

To be more precise if I refresh current page which ID is `4` then `console.log('updated', newProgress)` inside the if statement outputs `null` 
and `console.log(id, old)`at the end of the function outputs

```
4 (8) ["6", "5", "6", "3", "6", "3", "4", "2"]
```

and if I go to the page which ID is 5 the same console statments print
 `updated (9) ["6", "5", "6", "3", "6", "3", "4", "2", 5]` representing new array
and
 `5 (8) ["6", "5", "6", "3", "6", "3", "4", "2"]` represting old array. The 5 was already in old array but it got added to new array aswell. I have no clue why it acts like this.

**Solved**
If anyone ever need this use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-persistent-state
and don't do anything with local storage directly. I really had no idea that it's vue related problem.
I've solved this in this way:

```
import persistentState from 'vue-persistent-state'

let initialState = {
  progress: []
}

Vue.use(persistentState, initialState)
```

and my function looks like this

```
updateProgress (id) {
  if (this.progress.indexOf(id.toString()) === -1) {
    this.progress.push(id.toString())
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `id`? What is `old`? Are you comparing strings to integers?

Comment: id is id of current page, old is array of ids which are already recorded before

Comment: What is the **type** of `id`?  Is it a `string` or a `number`?   This isn't answerable without a [mcve].  What is your input?

Comment: `.split()` will never return `null`. If the item is not in local storage, however, `.getItem()` will and that first statement will therefore throw an exception.

Comment: `.split` returns an array not a single string so you will need to loop through the array.

Comment: @nurdyguy [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: @Amy id is a string

Comment: I gotta say, this implementation is broken.  If your array of ids is `[12345]`, and your current id is `12`, it won't do what you're wanting.

Comment: @str I've learned about all these functions in that site so I already read that

Comment: @Žilvinas Please change your code into something we all can copy and run ourselves. Without you supplying the actual values of `old` and `id`, we can't really help you. See [mcve].

Comment: @str Sorry, just so many comments didn't notice that, id is typeof string and members of old are typeof strings but they are actually numbers, maybe that's bad practice here

Comment: @Amy why, if I have ids separated by commas?

Comment: @str I didn't say you couldn't do `.indexOf` on an array, just noting that it is an array.  In order for his `.indexOf` to work here the data would need to be something like `...,<id>,...` which is probably isn't.  Honestly, a simple `console.log(localStorage.getItem('visited'))` would probably answer just about all of his question.

Comment: @Ivar well this is actually in vue.js project and id is from the route

Comment: @Žilvinas because if your array is `[12345, 4567]`, and your current id is `12`, the index of `12` isn't `-1`.  It won't do what you're expecting.

Comment: `.split()`  returns an array so it will never be eq to `null`. Also, to reiterate what @Ivar said, we need sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are some wonky things with the code, it should actually work in general. Here is a runnable example with a faked localStorage for demo purposes.

```js
const fakeStorage = { 'visited': null };

const getItem = (key) => fakeStorage[key];
const setItem = (key, value) => { fakeStorage[key] = value };

const updateProgress = id => {
  let old = (getItem('visited') || '').split(',');
  if (old === null) old = ' ';
  if (old.indexOf(id) === -1) {
    let newProgress = [old, id];
    setItem('visited', newProgress.join(','));
  }
  
  console.log(getItem('visited'));
};

updateProgress('a');
updateProgress('a');
updateProgress('b');
updateProgress('a');
```

Starting with an empty value, the only thing I needed to change was wrapping the `getItem('visited')` with a default of `''` before splitting `(getItem('visited') || '').split(',')`, since you can't `split()` on `null`.

Doing this, the `old === null` bit is redundant and unnecessarily (and probably detrimental since it adds an extra blank string. Better to just remove that bit, and instead properly check before splitting and initialize a default array instead:

```js
const fakeStorage = { 'visited': null };

const getItem = (key) => fakeStorage[key];
const setItem = (key, value) => { fakeStorage[key] = value };

const updateProgress = id => {
  let old = getItem('visited');
  old = (old && old.split(',')) || [];
  
  if (old.indexOf(id) === -1) {
    const newProgress = [].concat(old, id);
    setItem('visited', newProgress.join(','));
  }
  
  console.log(getItem('visited'));
};

updateProgress('a');
updateProgress('a');
updateProgress('b');
updateProgress('a');
```

Your also better off using `[].concat(old, id)` instead of the odd join. While it technically worked, it was basically doing `[[1,2,3], 4].join()` which is a little weird.

That said, your code should probably work as is. If it doesn't, then it likely isn't a code issue, but a data issue.

If your `id` contains any commas, that's one thing that'll completely blow it up. Likewise, if you accidentally got something wonky in there already, that could blow it up too. Clear your local storage and try it again.

Add a `console.log()` to the end of your `updateProgress()` that outputs the `id`, `old`, and `newProgress` to make sure you have good data going in.

Comment: Thanks, this was very detailed and informative answer. I've applied the changes which you suggested. However, I still can't get it to work properly, if I refresh the page then it doesn't record the value but if if I change the route and then go back to the same route it records it again. This is probably some kind of vue.js issue

Comment: At the end of `updateProgress()` add `console.log(id, old)` and inside the `if` statement, add `console.log('updated', newProgress)`. What are the outputs after doing it a few times (update your answer with them so you can format it nicely). That might help illustrate what is going wrong.

Comment: Updated the answer but don't know how to format it nicely though. It seems that values are right I don't understand why it works like this, I probably shouldn't use local storage in vue projects as I read it might behave differently.

Comment: I think I see your problem. It looks like your ID is actually an integer, not a string. Try `old.indexOf(id+"") === -1` to cast it as a string before searching for it. =)